# Generics is for type sefty? what about derived type?

Tags: generics, c#-3.0

I am using .net 3.5 framework.
below is my code.

```
class Base {}

class Derived : Base {}

class Program {
  static Main() {
    IList<Base> base_col = new List<Base>();
    base_col.Add(new Derived()); // Do you think this line code is good?
  }
}
```

Do you think generics will be the good idea for type check?

I will go one step ahead.

```
static Main() { 
  IList<Derived> base_col = new List<Derived>(); 
  Process(base_col); // error. 
} 
static Process(IEnumarable<Base> baseCollection) { }
```

Why code breaks here?

Comment: If you think that's interesting, wait until you try to pass an IList<Derived> to a method that accepts an IList<Base>

Answer (score 1):

Since `Derived` is a `Base` as well, there is no problem with the code shown - and it has little to do with generics.

Regarding your edit: the code you supply does work in .NET 4 where the `IEnumerable<>` interface is contravariant. The versions before didn't use this feature (support for co-/contravariance in interfaces has apparently been in the CLR since V2, but no language emitted code using the feature until V4 of the .NET Framework).

For this specific case you can use the `Cast<>` LINQ function safely though:

```
static Main() { 
  IList<Derived> base_col = new List<Derived>(); 
  Process(base_col.Cast<Base>());
}
```

Comment: I completly agree with you... pls find my updated code above.